# visual c++ runtime 2008 sp1 64bit missing

Tags: vvvv

I am trying to install vvvv but I am missing visual c++ runtime 2009 sp1 64bit. I tried several things but wasn't able to make it work. Here is an image of the setup:
[install vvvv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0msE.png)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally after 2 hours my computer wasn't a total ass and began to work. I don't know exactly what I did but I was able to get vvvv installed and ready for work!

Answer (score 0):

Restart is usually required after such installations. Good luck with your vvvv journey!